# SWIG: using imported external type

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am trying to wrap some libraries written in C++ to interface with JAVA using SWIG.

I have one C++ struct in one library used in one C++ function of another library as an argument.

**common.h**

```
namespace rina {
    namespace cdap_rib {
        typedef struct{
        int size_;
        void* message_;
        } ser_obj_t;
    }
}
```

This library is wrapped producing a class called `eu.irati.librina.ser_obj_t` in JAVA. That's fine. Then I have

**utilities.h**

```
class IPCPConfigEncoder {
    public:
        void encode (rina::cdap_rib::ser_obj_t& ser_obj);
}
```

which is wraped with SWIG producing

```
  public void encode(SWIGTYPE_p_rina__cdap_rib__ser_obj_t ser_obj) {
    ...
}
```

in a JAVA class. Looking around in I found ([SWIG Importing generated class from a different module and package into the current class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499202/swig-importing-generated-class-from-a-different-module-and-package-into-the-curr)) and I added to .i

```
%typemap(javaimports) SWIGTYPE 
%{
    import eu.irati.librina.ser_obj_t;
%}
```

which produced

```
import eu.irati.librina.ser_obj_t;
public void encode(SWIGTYPE_p_rina__cdap_rib__ser_obj_t ser_obj) {
    ...
}
```

Then, I have a couple of questions

1. The `import` is added to all the java classes... how can I enclose it only to the desired class?
2. How can I tell SWIG to change `SWIGTYPE_p_rina__cdap_rib__ser_obj_t` for `eu.irati.librina.ser_obj_t`.

Note: Since `common.h` and `utilities.h` are in different libraries I can not put them together in the same swig module.

Comment: Does my example at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30413268/168175 solve this for you?

Comment: well, the problem is that both are different modules placed in different folders. When I import the other .i it does not find the includes because it seems that both includes must be in the same folder.

Comment: You can use the -I flag to SWIG to set the include search path.

Comment: Yes, this worked (together with some changes) but thanks, I'ma answering my own question thanks to your contribution

Comment: You should write up an answer yourself so that future readers can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Felxo pointed in the coments, the only solution is to tell swig to understand also the other libraries interface wraping (so headers and how are they wrapped).

What I did:

1. I copied `common.i` into utilities wrapping folder.
2. I added into `utilities.i`

   ```
   /* this is the "copied" common.i */
   %import "common.i"
   %pragma(java) jniclassimports=%{
   import eu.irati.librina.ser_obj_t;
   %}
   ```

   to add the import of the proxy class (you should change thais to point to your proxy class from a java path)
3. Remove from the copied `common.i` the unecessary instructions like `%template`, remember that, at this point, you are only "importing" the common.h, not wrapping it (you already wraped it before). Actually, the `common.i` should only include:

   ```
    %{
       #include "common.h"
    }%
   ```

   but no

   ```
    %include "common.h"
   ```
4. Tell SWIG where are is the `common.h` as well as where is the `utilities.h`using the `-I` option