# SWIG - problem with duplicated java files

Tags: java, c++, swig

Problem I'm trying to solve in shortest example looks like that.
I have 2 swig's interface files.

- first swig file `Common.i` looks like that:

```
/* Common.i */
%module Common
%include "Common.hpp"
```

I generate swig wrappers with command:

`swig -c++ -java -package com.wrappers.Common -outdir "wrappers/Common" -o "wrappers_cpp/swig_Common_wrapper.cpp" "Common.i"`

`Common.hpp` has definitions of class `A` and `B`, so this swig command above generates files `A.java` and `B.java` in catalog `wrappers/Common`

- second swig file `Example.i` looks like that:

```
/* Example.i */
%module Example

%include "Common.i"

%include "Example.hpp"
```

and again I generate swig wrappers with command:

`swig -c++ -java -package com.wrappers.Example -outdir "wrappers/Example" -o "wrappers_cpp/swig_Example_wrapper.cpp" "Example.i"`

And here my problem begins:
In catalog `wrappers/Example` I have duplicate files `A.java` and `B.java`, because I included `Common.i` in `Example.i`.

I would like to have one copy of those classes above.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication?

Comment: Maybe you should not run the first swig command. Since "Common.i" is included in "Example.i", it will be parsed as well at the same time (as if you wrote two modules in a single interface file). That being said, I'm not sure we can define several modules in a single interface file.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to define several modules in a single interface file but it's not a solution for me. 
I want to include `Common.i` in more than one swig's interface. So again even if I define `Common.i` in `Example.i` and in another file `Example2.i` I will have duplicated `java` files in `Example` and `Example2` catalogs.

Comment: Try `%import "Common.i"` instead of `%include "Common.i"`.

Comment: From [here](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Modules.html) they use indeed the `%import` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Working with Modules: Basics](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Modules_nn1), either of the following should work:

```cpp
%import "Common.i"
```

```cpp
%import(module="Common") "Common.hpp"
```

According to [File Imports](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Preprocessor_nn3):

> The purpose of `%import` is to collect certain information from another SWIG interface file or a header file without actually generating any wrapper code.

Comment: It works for files duplications, but now files ganarated from `Example.i`  are in different catalog, and also in different package, so `java` files from `Example.i` doesn't know anything about `A.java` and `B.java` because of missing imports. 
Do I have to add all those imports by myself in swig interface files?

Comment: Another thing is that generated classes in `A.java` and `B.java` have protected constructors and I can only use them if I am in the same package, but I'm not.
So another question is if I can force those constructors to be public ?

Comment: @AnDevi Sorry I use SWIG with Python not Java so not sure of the solution. The .i files normally need `%{ #include "Common.hpp" %}` in addition to `%include` to add the headers to the generated wrapper. That could be part of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know about `%{ #include "Common.hpp" %}`, but missing imports, are in `java` not `c++`, I can add `java` import in similar way, bet there is still problem with protected constructors in `java`.

Comment: Ok, I found answers to my questions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499202/swig-importing-generated-class-from-a-different-module-and-package-into-the-curr